# I need to make Toggle Switches for Java

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, radio-button, toggle

Hello Guys can someone tell me how i can make a few toggle switches in Java? Specifically two out of three switches that toggle off when one is turned on?

[LIKE THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROT88.gif)

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.  Did you have a question for us?

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question. It is very difficult to understand what you're asking. Preferably provide some code too, and where you're stuck.

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/5mWKUktmOeRcMGOeLG/giphy.gif How i can make like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have `swt1` and `swt2`.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Switch swt1;
    private Switch swt2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        swt1 = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.swt1);
        swt2 = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.swt2);


        swt1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if(b == true)
                    swt2.setChecked(false);
                else
                    swt2.setChecked(true);
            }
        });

        swt2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if(b == true)
                    swt1.setChecked(false);
                else
                    swt1.setChecked(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can add as many switches as you want. Just use `switch.setChecked(true)` to toggle a switch on, and `switch.setChecked(false)` to toggle the switch off.

Be sure to ask any questions!

Comment: Thank you so much finally its working  :)